# How to create a Block contains some Blocks in Eyeshot devdept

Tags: c#, model, block, eyeshot

I've tried to grouping some Entities in a Block object and it is done. But I need to group some Blocks of Entities.
Is there any way to grouping Blocks and add them to the main Model object?
Just like CAD software you can create assembly of components and add it in another assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the BlockReference entity for this purpose.
The [Building sample](https://www.devdept.com/support/samples#building) is a good start point for this.